# WordPress storing CSS on cache file?

Tags: css, wordpress

My wordpress is automatically storing css in cache file. I want to change the design, because the inspect tool of chrome showing me the cache file so i cannot change design directly in the original css file as i don't know the original file path.
how can I change the background image if i don't know the original css file path in wordpress.

Comment: empty the browser cache. If it's still there, it is NOT a matter of the cache, but is stored in some stylesheet or similar (a plugin for example can have seperate CSS styles which would reside somewhere in the plugin folder)

Comment: after clearing cache as you said it is making another. .css file in cache folder while removing the previous one. so any other solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to add parameters to the CSS file url and change the value before uploading:

```
style.css?v=2
```

Comment: How? did you mean that I should make a new style.css?v=2 file

Comment: just add `?v=2` at the end of the CSS file.